# WSO2 BAM - ESB sinchronization

Tags: connection, wso2, esb, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

Hello Stackoverflow & WSO2 community,

I want to thank you for the ongoing support from the beginning of my architecture building. I'm not much skilled at creating SOA solutions, and your support has been, is and will be much important.

While trying to solve the ESB problem, I was trying to connect BAM and ESB following the tutorial I found in `wso2bam-1.3.2\samples\eventing-mode-mediation-monitoring`.

My steps has been:

- Adding the repository in WSO2 ESB;
- Adding the "BAM Mediation Statistics Data Publisher" feature;
- Enabling statistics on a simple service;
- Adding the ESB server in the WSO2 BAM as: `https://<ip-address>:9443/carbon/` or `https://<ip-address>:9443/carbon/services`, with

  - Data Collection Method: Eventing
  - Type of Data: Mediation;
- Running the proxy service from an external client (Netbeans java application) - note that statistics were reported into the graphic near the proxy service of the ESB
- Checking the BAM - but, for instance, the Service Calls gadget says:

> No services found for the server `https://<ip-address>:9443`

I deduce something went wrong.

If you can help me again, I'm going to begin thinking about a way to give you some kind of useful feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It seems BAM 1.3.2 seems to have an issue with the ESB. Could you try with [BAM 1.3.0](http://dist.wso2.org/downloads/bam/1.3.0/wso2bam-1.3.0.zip)? It should just work.

Comment: I've tried both with 1.3.0 and 1.3.2 and in both solutions he knows that my server is running, but I still have "no information available".
If you can help me in any way, it's quite important for me making this point work.
I'm new to SOA and not great at solving problems, so I think the only solution is yours :)

Comment: Anyways, I followed the tutorial in the sample folder of BAM, (eventing-mode-mediation-monitoring), set "eventing" and "mediation when adding the service. Set the server to https://machineName:9443 and Subscription EPR to the standard https://machineIP:9463/services/BAMServerUserDefinedDataSubscriberService.

If you can understand where I'm doing the wrong thing, please tell me!

Comment: Also, if you can be patient there is a brand smacking new BAM version coming out soon. It's a complete re-write of the old version. Milestone builds are available here, http://wso2.com/products/business-activity-monitor

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will consider it for my research!